# Dynamically setting download location Selenium dotnet

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a test project where I have to extract data from bills that are on a website using Selenium.
My problem is that for each bill I have to create a folder with the bill's name and download there the necessary files and I don't know how to set that download location dynamically. I know that you can use ChromeOptions in WebDrivers's constructor to specify the default download location, but that's not a solution for me because I would have to do the navigation + login process every time since it will open a new web driver

I have a robot class with multiple methods (login, find table with bills, process table etc)
and here I want to download the files and this is how I create my options. In my robot class I have a private webDriver instance which I use in the code

```
   var options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Constants.DownloadLocation + "\\" + downloadEndpoint);
```

Comment: Why you have to open the website every time? You can probably just open a new tab on the same driver and let the cookies do their work so you don't have to login again. That maybe will do?

Comment: I think that it will be kinda hard on resources. Consider that I that thousands of bills. And for each bill a new tab :-?

Comment: But you can always close the last tab after you open the new one. Seems like a good option for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dynamically changing the default downloads folder in selenium driver, you can continue downloading the files to the default downloads folder and then to create a new folder per each file name and move the downloaded file there.

Comment: Is there a library that you recomand?

Comment: You don't need any special library for this. Simply create a folder and move the downloaded files there